# how to get the same name as an output image using a code to remove watermarks?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This is a code for removing the watermarks from images, but i have a simple problem in some images which is the name of the output image is missing a digit in some images. This is the code:

```
#coding:utf-8
import os
import os.path
from PIL import Image


outputFormat = '.png'

def hasBlackAround(x, y, distance, img):
    w, h = img.size
    startX = 0 if x - distance < 0 else x - distance
    startY = 0 if y - distance < 0 else y - distance
    endX = w - 1 if x + distance > w - 1 else x + distance
    endY = h - 1 if y + distance > h - 1 else y + distance
    hasBlackAround = False
    for j in range(startX, endX):
        for k in range(startY, endY):
            r, g, b = img.getpixel((j, k))
            if r < 130 and g < 130 and b < 130:
                return True
    return False

currentPath = os.getcwd()
fileList = os.listdir(currentPath)
for file in fileList:
    if(os.path.isdir(file)):
        targetFiles = os.listdir(file)
        outputDir = file + '/output/'
        if not os.path.isdir(outputDir):
            os.makedirs(outputDir)
        for targetFile in targetFiles:
            try:
                img = Image.open(file + '/' + targetFile)
                w, h = img.size
                rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')
                for x in range(0, w - 1):
                    for y in range(0, h - 1):
                        if not hasBlackAround(x, y, 1, rgb_im):
                            rgb_im.putpixel((x, y), (255, 255, 255))
                rgb_im.save(outputDir + targetFile[0:targetFile.rfind('.')] + outputFormat)
            except IOError:
                print targetFile + ' is not a image file'
            except  Exception as e:
                print e
print 'Done'
```

example image name: 11A087
output image name: 11A08.png

I need the output to be 11A087.png. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
targetFile[0:targetFile.rfind('.')]
```

This is the problem. You're trying to slice off everything past the rightmost period of the filename, but if the filename doesn't have a period, `rfind` returns `-1` and it slices off the last letter. Simpler example:

```
>>> targetFile = "foobar.png"
>>> targetFile[0:targetFile.rfind(".")]
'foobar'
>>> targetFile = "bazqux"
>>> targetFile[0:targetFile.rfind(".")]
'bazqu'
```

Try using `os.path.splitext` instead of slicing the string yourself. It exists for exactly this purpose.

```
>>> import os
>>> targetFile = "foobar.png"
>>> os.path.splitext(targetFile)[0]
'foobar'
>>> targetFile = "bazqux"
>>> os.path.splitext(targetFile)[0]
'bazqux'
```

It's also a good idea to use `os.path.join` instead of concatenating directory names yourself. You never know when your code is going to be run on an OS that's picky about separator characters.

```
rgb_im.save(os.path.join(outputDir, os.path.splitext(targetFile)[0] + outputFormat))
```

Comment: Thank you. all my images are just names without extensions, so i just passed the target image without any slicing and it worked.